# How to avoid pressing Alt-TAB twice in Ubuntu GNOME to switch to previous window?

Tags: 18.04, gnome

When I am pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> in Ubuntu GNOME, a list of applications appears and the selected one is current one. So I need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> once more to switch to previous application.

How to disable this "feature"? Is it possible to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> never ever show the current application selected? How to force it to select something else?

---

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5s_4GnQJi3s

Comment: In 18.04 LTS Alt-Tab does indeed give a list of applications but the selected one in not the current one but the next in line. As an alternative, you could use GNOME extension Window List which will display a window list at the bottom of the screen. You may need to install an earlier version.

Comment: For me it shows current.

Comment: For example, I can edit text in editor, then press Alt-TAB once and then continue editing, because I will be in the same window.

Comment: That is not regular behaviour. Not on 18.04 anymore, but I wonder if other users on 18.04 experience this issue.

Comment: Is it possible for you if you use Workspaces to have your editor open in, say WS1 and other open app in WS2 etc so that when Alt-Tab it returns you by default to your editor (just as a work round)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question (title and/or body) to clarify: you have "window" in the title and application in the "body".

Comment: I also experience this. Seems to happen after a while - perhaps after sleep.
Very annoying. Reboot temporarily fixes it.

Comment: I also have this in 20.04... very irritating

Comment: I came across this issue Manjaro with Gnome 43.1. In my case the issue can be temporarily fixed by restarting the gnome shell: press Alt+F2, then input a 'r', enter

Comment: @z.h. Unfortunately, `Alt+F2` and `r` does not work with Wayland. I can also confirm that reboot resolves the issue for me (running GNOME 42.6 with Wayland on F36). So, it must not be config, but some bogus GNOME state.

Comment: Gnome 43.4: still an issue. It also seems that this behavior depends on the specific application (perhaps gtk version it uses or something like that?) -- some apps, e.g. for me, evince behaves as expected, while others, e.g. vscode or firefox don't...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue in the later versions of Gnome as well. I was able to fix this by reassigning the shortcuts for window and application switching in Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is a work spaces issue. I experienced the issue just as you describe it ie "the selected one is current one", and thus we must press alt tab then tab again to move to the next app. I closed one of my work spaces (which had a single app open in it) and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that software update app was minimised and when I closed it, it solved the issue for me.
however I thank @neverdimed because he has confirmed that it was not a software issue.